# Polish law - is facebook id personal data in the context of the Act on the protection of personal data

Tags: facebook

I am writing mobile application, users are login by Facebook. In my database I want to collect same data (hight score in game, etc - data in any way could not identify person), but data will be connect with user by facebook id. So, my question is if facebook id is personal data in the context of the Act on the protection of personal data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this.  StackOverflow doesn't quite have the reason "seeking legal advise".  But I wouldn't recommend anonymous people on the web for that purpose.

Comment: I am writing this post in order to get same links to law resources. Of course opinion without reference is not valuable.